# How does SSD wear leveling work when I have 2 partitions?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, physical-wear

How does SSD wear leveling work when I have 2 partitions?

If I trim the first partition can't I run the risk that writes to my second partition will end up overwriting the data on the first, since parts of it have been marked as good for writing? If not, how can the SSD know about partitions?

Thanks for any help in clearing this up, I must be missing something.

Comment: Sure it will write to blocks originally from whatever partition. They’re marked as deleted after all, using TRIM.

Comment: @DanielB But it can't lead to corruption, right? This was the main point of my question.

Comment: @Marian it will not lead to corruption. It is all handled by the drive controller.

Comment: It won’t lead to corruption because the FTL (see linked Q) will know where in the “outer view” of the storage device it belongs.